# How do bitwise operations work on expressions within variable assignments in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, reverse-engineering

I'm learning reverse engineering, and I have the following snippet which I am trying to make sense of:

```
var = strcmp("C:\\Windows\\System32\\svchost.exe", pe.szExeFile);
if (var)
  var = -(var < 0) | 1;
if (var)
{
  // additional code here
}
```

I think I understand most of what is going on here, but I'm confused about the purpose of the
`var = -(var < 0) | 1;` line. I'm only very vaguely familiar with C/C++, so I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around what this line does.

I understand that it's a bitwise `OR`, but I'm unsure how the `-(var < 0)` works. Is the expression inside the parentheses evaluated to a 1 or 0 and then the negative is applied and the `OR`? Is it evaluated as a boolean? If so, how does the `|` work on a boolean?

Or am I totally missing the point here?

Comment: in C the result of `<` is an `int` (either 0 or 1)

Comment: If you work out the bits (and assuming two's complement representation), that's just another way to write `var = (var < 0) ? -1 : 1`. It could be a legitimate compiler optimization (to avoid branching), but it's not the code one would normally write for that.

Comment: @M.M - thanks, I can at least logic through it with that information

Comment: @dxiv - when I initially read it I thought maybe C ternary syntax used | instead of ?, since that was the only way I could parse it in a way that made sense to me, so that is good to know, thanks!

Comment: It doesn't make much sense. You could remove it and the following `if` test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strcmp()` returns one of three possible results:

- < 0
- 0
- > 0

Assumed common two's complement, after the first `if` the variable `var` will be

- -1 for the former "< 0"
- 0 for the former "= 0"
- +1 for the former "> 0"

However, the second `if` will be taken only if `var` is non-zero.

The "mysterious" first `if` has no effect, as far as the source is concerned that you show.

Comment: Perhaps the actual value of `var` is used in the code that isn't shown.

Comment: @NateEldredge That's why I wrote "_the source […] that you show_".

Comment: After dealing with this for a few days, my guess is it is decompiled and the second if is the implementation of strcmp to force an answer of -1/0/+1 rather than the more general 'negative/zero/positive' in the strcmp spec

Comment: @spakejaniel That sounds sensible. However, some implementations of `strcmp()` I saw don't care.